# A question about heat equation involving polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the heat equation $u_t=\triangle u$ in $R^3$, where $u=u(x,y,z,t)$ and $\triangle u=u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}$. Suppose u is radially symmetric ( u is a constant that can be represented as a function of $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and t, say u=U(r,t). Show $U(r,t)$ solves $U_t=U_{rr}+\frac{2U_r}{r}$

I have hard time solve due to cartesian and polar coordinate switches. A hint is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly we have $u_t=U_t$. 
To compute the other derivatives, we need to use the chain rule:
\begin{equation}u_x(x,y,z,t)=U_r\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}u_{xx}(x,y,z,t)=U_{rr}\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+U_r\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}-U_r\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot\frac{x^2}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3} \end{equation}
The other derivatives can be computed analogously and you get the same expressions with $x$ replaced by $y$ respectively $z$.
Now we can use the fact that $u$ solves the heat equation to see that
\begin{equation}0=u_t(x,y,z,t)-\triangle u(x,y,z,t)=U_t\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)-U_{rr}\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}-3U_r\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+U_r\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},t\bigg)\cdot\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^3}\end{equation}
If we replace $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ by $r$ we get
\begin{equation}0=U_t(r,t)-U_{rr}(r,t)-2U_r(r,t)\frac{1}{r} \end{equation}